# Spring boot won't rollback tests if Datasource extends DelegatingDataSource

Tags: java, database, spring-boot, rollback

I have CustomDataSource:

```
public class CustomDataSource extends DelegatingDataSource {}
```

Next, I create JdbcTemplate bean using CustomDataSource:

```
@Configuration
public class Config {
  @Bean
  public JdbcTemplate CustomJdbcTemplate(DataSource dataSource) {
    CustomDataSource source = new CustomDataSource();
    source.setTargetDataSource(dataSource);
    return new JdbcTemplate(source);
  }
}
```

Now, running tests:

```
@SpringBootTest
@RunWith(SpringRunner.class)
@Transactional
public class CustomRepositoryTest {

  @Autowired
  private JdbcTemplate jdbcTemplate;

  public void insertId(int id) {
    jdbcTemplate.update("INSERT INTO products(id) VALUES (?)", id);
  }

  @Test
  public void testId1() {
    insertId(10);
  }

  @Test
  public void testId2() {
    insertId(10);
  }
}
```

**The problem:** Spring's test auto rollback with @Transactional is not working. I get *"Key (id)=(10) already exists"* because id must be unique and no rollback after every test. 
These two test work if I pass dataSource directly (rollback after every test):

```
@Configuration
public class Config {
  @Bean
  public JdbcTemplate CustomJdbcTemplate(DataSource dataSource) {
    return new JdbcTemplate(dataSource);
  }
}
```

Is there way to fix it by keeping DelegatingDataSource?